# How to share a randomly viewing text?

Tags: java, android, sdk, adt, share-button

I want the user to be able to share what is randomly viewing text from a set of texts but it seems very complicated. I tried to search for an answer but everyone talks about sharing images.

Here's my Java code:

```
public class Second extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        final TextView generatedtxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.generatedtxt);
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets (), "fonts/1.ttf");

        generatedtxt.setTypeface(custom_font);

        Button generatebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.generatebtn);

        final String[] gn = {"text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5"};

        generatebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int rando = (int) (Math.random() *5);
                generatedtxt.setText(gn[rando]);

            }
        });


    }

}
```

and this is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:background="@drawable/bg2"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/generatebtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sharebtn"
    android:text="@string/generatebtn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sharebtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/sharebtn" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/generatedtxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/generatebtn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/gt"
    android:textSize="40sp" />
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create an `ACTION_SEND` intent and put your text as the `EXTRA_TEXT` extra.

```
int rando = (int) (Math.random() *5);
String text = gn[rando];

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Please check [Sending Text Content](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-text-content) in the Android documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but every time I push the generate button "generatebtn", it changes the text and opens the share activity. What I want is when I like a text, I want to be able to push another button "sharebtn" to share the showing text. :)

Comment: This was just an example. :) You need to add another button, and in its OnClickListener run this code, only using `generatedtxt.getText().toString()` instead of the `text` variable.